# How to convert two channel audio into one channel audio

Tags: python, audio

I am playing around with some audio processing in python.  Right now I have the audio as a 2x(Large Number) numpy array.  I want to combine the channels since I only want to try some simple stuff.  I am just unsure how I should do this mathematically.  At first I thought this is kind of like converting an RGB image to gray-scale where you would average each of the color channels to create a gray pixel.  Then I thought that maybe I should add them due to the superposition principal of waves (then again average is just adding and dividing by two.)  Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Comment: What I would do is take the sample from the left and right channel, add them together, divide the result by two, then save that as the mono sample value, making sure to do it in a way that didn't have the possibility to overflow, and also rounding properly. That's how any audio program typically does it from what I have seen.

Comment: Ok great just making sure.  I have never worked with audio before.  If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert any stereo audio to mono, what I have always seen is the following:

For each pair of left and right samples:

1. Add the values of the samples together in a way that will not overflow
2. Divide the resulting value by two
3. Use this resulting value as the sample in the mono track -  make sure to round it properly if you are converting it to an integer value from a floating point value

Answer (score 2):

i handle this by using Matlab.python can do the same. (left-channel+right-channel)/2.0